# What advantage from Required attribute for nullable field in entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, required

For example I have an entity `Entity` and it has a field `SomeValue` of type `double?`.

And I set `Required` attribute for this field. Does this field behaves like `double`?

```
public class Entity
{
   [Required]
   public double? SomeValue { get;set;}
}
```

Comment: With a `double` it will default to 0 if no value is supplied, whereas with `double?` it will be null so you can determine whether a value has been supplied. Adding `[Required]` to a no nullable type is redundant as it will always have a value.

Comment: it behaves like a double that could also potentially be null.  If you're using ASP.NET MVC here, `[Required]` will force the user to input a value into the input control

Comment: @Sinatr, yes, but on the other hand, it make `SomeValue` required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a practical example, imagine you have an asp.net core controller that takes this request:

```
public class ExampleRequest
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

If you execute this request with an **empty payload**, the validation will **succeed**. But how? If you omitted `Id` from the request, and it is required, it should fail...

In reality, `Id` defaults to [`Guid.Empty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.empty?view=net-7.0), so `[Required]` sees a valid Guid and it passes validation.

How can we guarantee that an empty payload fails validation? With a **nullable required field**:

```
public class ExampleRequest
{
    [Required]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

This way, an empty payload will result in a null `Id` that fails validation.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the .NET data type in the first place. Rather, it is the client side counterpart of a database column being nullable or not. 
If you don't provide a value to a property marked with the `Required` attribute, then the entity is invalidated without making a database server roundtrip.

Strictly spoken, nullable .NET data types don't make sense for not nullable database columns. But that's not really the point...

Comment: If i have a property with `?` and `[Required]` both. then what does that mean. And when it shall be used? How come we can make it optional which is `?` and then `[Rerquired]` both at the same time. Please guide me. I am confused.